# Reactjs Nested Routing: Nested Children Are Not Rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to make a page with nested routing, however I can't seem to get the nested part working. I've made this sample which models the way in which I'm attempting routing on my page.

I made some progress in which I was previously using exact in it's parent element which confused me further. However I cannot understand why this route isn't being rendered. I've been stuck on this for a while.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <p>Main Application</p>

        <Link to="/">Root</Link>
        <Link to="/Settings">Settings</Link>

        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Index />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/Settings">
              <div>
                <Settings />
              </div>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

function Index() {
  return <h1>Index</h1>;
}

function Settings() {
  //let match = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Settings</h1>

      <Link to="Settings/Groups">Groups</Link>
      <Link to="Settings/Users">Users</Link>
      <Link to="Settings/Dashboards">Dashboards</Link>

      <Switch>
        <Route path={"Settings/Groups"}>
          <Groups />
        </Route>
        <Route path={"Settings/Users"}>
          <Users />
        </Route>
        <Route path={"Settings/Dashboards"}>
          <Dashboards />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

function Groups() {
  return <h1>Groups</h1>;
}

function Users() {
  return <h1>Users</h1>;
}

function Dashboards() {
  return <h1>Dashboards</h1>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your nested child component add a slash’/‘ in the prefix.

Comment: Strangely enough this is the correct answer. I say it's strange because the code above was an example I tried in some Reactjs sandbox. In my actual project it was from which value in the return of useRouteMatch I was using. So it was also because of a wrong path.

Comment: This happened because react-router-dom is following a convention to have a slash for a path to get attached to the base url else it would keep on appending to pathname. Also, this is how we give paths on our machine as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it has to be something to do with your urls. I have rewritten your code to utlise the useRouterMatch() hook more as that might help, it also matches the react-router-dom nesting example.

Have a read through the react-router-dom docs as they have a good example for nesting https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting

```js
function Settings() {
  const { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Settings</h1>

      <Link to={`${url}/Groups`}>Groups</Link>
      <Link to={`${url}/Users`}>Users</Link>
      <Link to={`${url}/Dashboards`}>Dashboards</Link>

      <Switch>
        <Route path={`${path}/Groups`}>
          <Groups />
        </Route>
        <Route path={`${path}/Users`}>
          <Users />
        </Route>
        <Route path={`${path}/Dashboards`}>
          <Dashboards />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```